# PHP - iterate through array and only show certain values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to show a selection of transactions using PHP and Paypal's NVP `TransactionSearch` method.

I successfully get the transactions to appear but i cannot tidy the response up and show only the specific values i am after - in this case being just the following 4 values per transaction:

```
L_TIMESTAMP, 
L_TYPE, 
L_TRANSACTIONID
```

My current code is:

```
$request = http_build_query(array(
    "METHOD"    => $action,
    "VERSION"   => $config['version'],
    "USER"      => $config['username'],
    "PWD"       => $config['password'],
    "SIGNATURE" => $config['signature'],
    "STARTDATE" => $start,
    "EMAIL" => $email,
));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$result) {
    echo 'no results';
}

parse_str($result, $result);

foreach($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' => '.$value."<br />";
}
```

which outputs everything in one as below :

```
L_TIMESTAMP0 => 2014-01-15T11:29:21Z
L_TIMESTAMP1 => 2014-01-15T11:09:05Z
L_TIMEZONE0 => GMT
L_TIMEZONE1 => GMT
L_TYPE0 => Refund
L_TYPE1 => Payment
L_TRANSACTIONID0 => 7MY22222222222914
L_TRANSACTIONID1 => 2045555555555594D

and so on...
```

How can i instead output it like this: (so it goes through each transaction then the next rather than each 'value' and onto the next, plus not show the TIMEZONE key)

```
L_TIMESTAMP0 => 2014-01-15T11:29:21Z
L_TYPE0 => Refund
L_TRANSACTIONID0 => 7MY22222222222914

L_TIMESTAMP1 => 2014-01-15T11:09:05Z
L_TYPE1 => Payment
L_TRANSACTIONID1 => 2045555555555594D
```

Comment: what does `$result` look like before you run `parse_str`

Comment: You have to use `array_filter()`

Comment: if i simply remove the `parse_str` from the above code i get nothing outputted on the page

Comment: Asking two questions in one is not very effective to get good answers. "How to show only the values from wanted keys ?" has tons of duplicate on SO

Answer (score 3):

I think an array of arrays will be a better option:

```
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
    preg_match('~([A-Z_]+)(\d+)$~', $k, $m);
    $nested[$m[2]][$m[1]] = $v;
}
```

which creates a nested array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [L_TIMESTAMP] => 2014-01-15T11:29:21Z
            [L_TIMEZONE] => GMT
            [L_TYPE] => Refund
            [L_TRANSACTIONID] => 7MY22222222222914
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [L_TIMESTAMP] => 2014-01-15T11:09:05Z
            [L_TIMEZONE] => GMT
            [L_TYPE] => Payment
            [L_TRANSACTIONID] => 2045555555555594D
        )

)
```

It should be easy to generate your desired output from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` inside wrapping loop. Like this:

```
for ($i = 0; ; $i++) {
        $arr = array_filter($result, function ($v) use ($i) {
                return substr($v, -1) == $i;
        });
        if (!$arr) break;
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            echo $key.' => '.$value."<br />";
        }
}
```